# Software GNUPlot not launching from GNU Octave

Tags: osx-lion, gnuplot, octave

I'm trying to launch GNUPlot from Octave, but when I do I get the following error:

```
octave-3.4.0:3> plot(x,y)
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/X11/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libfontconfig.1.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/X11/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
 Reason: Incompatible library version: libfontconfig.1.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
/Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/bin/gnuplot: line 71: 53997 Trace/BPT trap: 5       GNUTERM="${GNUTERM}" GNUPLOT_HOME="${GNUPLOT_HOME}" PATH="${PATH}"   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" HOME="${HOME}" GNUHELP="${GNUHELP}"   DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="${DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH}" GNUPLOT_PS_DIR="${GNUPLOT_PS_DIR}"   DISPLAY="${DISPLAY}" GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR="${GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR}" "${ROOT}/bin/gnuplot-4.4.3"   "$@"
/Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/bin/gnuplot: line 71: 54003 Trace/BPT trap: 5       GNUTERM="${GNUTERM}" GNUPLOT_HOME="${GNUPLOT_HOME}" PATH="${PATH}" DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" HOME="${HOME}" GNUHELP="${GNUHELP}" DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="${DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH}" GNUPLOT_PS_DIR="${GNUPLOT_PS_DIR}" DISPLAY="${DISPLAY}" GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR="${GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR}" "${ROOT}/bin/gnuplot-4.4.3" "$@"
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
^C
```

---

First I tried this:

### Notes for Snow Leopard users:

1. `mkoctfile`

   Since OS X 10.6, the Apple shipped version of `gcc` builds 64bit binaries by default. As the libraries included with Octave.app version 3.2.3 are 32bit, you need to apply the following patch in order for mkoctfile to work:

   1. Open the folder `/Applications` in the Finder
   2. Right-click on Octave.app and select "Show Package Contents"
   3. Navigate to `/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin`
   4. Right-click on the file `mkoctfile` and select *Open with → Other… → TextEdit.app*
   5. Right after the line:

      ```
      # along with this program; If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
      ```

   add the lines

   ```
    CFLAGS="-m32 ${CFLAGS}"
   FFLAGS="-m32 ${FFLAGS}"
   CPPFLAGS="-m32 ${CPPFLAGS}"
   CXXFLAGS="-m32 ${CXXFLAGS}"
   LDFLAGS="-m32 ${LDFLAGS}"
   ```

   and save.
2. Gnuplot.app

   An update to system libraries introduced with OS X 10.6.5 has broken the functionality of the Gnuplot.app included with the Octave.app distribution, in order to use Gnuplot.app on OSX 10.6.5 and later, you can use the fix described below:

   1. Open the folder `/Applications` in the Finder
   2. Right-click on Gnuplot.app and select "Show Package Contents"
   3. Navigate to `/Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/bin`
   4. Right-click on the file `gnuplot` and select *Open with → Other… → TextEdit.app*
   5. Change the line:

      ```
      DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${ROOT}/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
      ```

   to

   ```
   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${ROOT}/lib"
   ```

   and save.

After that didn't work, I double checked to see I typed the correct information. After that didn't work, I installed MacPorts and used it to install Octave and GNUPlot. That hasn't cleared it up either.

I'm running OS X Lion 10.7.3

Comment: The current way of installing octave and gnuplot is using a package manager such as Homebrew; it's really just a few commands and you're done; see http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Homebrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.

I think the issue is that I hadn't installed gnuplot correctly. I got around this by downloading Maxima, which has another binary installation of gnuplot.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/Maxima-MacOS/

Once this was installed, I had to make sure that the environment was set to x11, because aquaterm was also giving me grief. I did this in octave by:

```
 > setenv GNUTERM 'x11'
```

And then

```
 > hist(randn(1,1000))
```

worked!

NB: This is a partial solution which is workable for me for now. There is surely a better solution...

Comment: `brew install gnuplot`

Answer (score 2):

The fix is here, in Octave 3.4.0

[GNU Octave Repository - 2011-04-21 binary of Octave 3.4.0 at SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20MacOSX%20Binary/2011-04-21%20binary%20of%20Octave%203.4.0/)